# Add color to a date range in month view in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using Full calendar and want to add color to a certain date range, So I have taken out start date and end date when we click on the month view tab.

But when In loop,only once it gets into the loop, and then I get this error.The main code is in viewDisplay

TypeError: t.getFullYear is not a function

Here is what I have tried.

```
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    editable: true,
   header: {
   left: 'prev,next today',
   center: 'title',
   right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,year'
  },   



   events: "cal_events.php",
 viewDisplay: function(view) {

            if (view.name == 'agendaDay') { 
                    //alert(view.name);

            }

            if (view.name == 'month') { 


         var start_day =view.start

        var end_day = view.end

     count = 1;   

        while(count<7)
        {

        var start_day =$.fullCalendar.formatDate(start_day,"yyyy-MM-dd");

        console.log(start_day);
        console.log(count);

         $("[data-date="+start_day+"]").css("background-color", "red");


        start_day = start_day.split('-');
        start_day[2] = parseInt(start_day[2])+2;
        if(start_day[2]<10) {
            start_day[2] = "0"+start_day[2];
        }
        start_day = start_day.join('-');

        count++;
        }


            }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you are trying to achive with this code but the problem is that in `$.fullCalendar.formatDate(start_day,"yyyy-MM-dd");` start_day should be a date object.

this should fix it:

```
start_day = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(new Date(start_day),"yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Thank U.. It worked this way.. Bt I could not understand y a date object?

Comment: Because this is the way that 'formatDate' works... :)

Answer (score 0):

In Full Calendar 3 and 4, you can do something as below:

```
                dayRender: function (date, cell) {
                    // colour the date range (DueDate - 30 days)
                    let cellDate = moment(date._d).format("Y-MM-DD");
                    //get the due date from the form / you can also  get it either as todays date  i.e. let dueDateEnd = date._d;
                    let dueDateEnd = $("#calendar").data("duedate");
                    console.log("____ original due Date_____" + dueDateEnd);

                    let dueDateStart = moment($("#calendar").data("duedate"), 'YYYY-MM-DD').subtract(30, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    console.log("____create DueDate start_____" + dueDateStart);

                    if (moment(cellDate).isBetween(dueDateStart, dueDateEnd)) {
                        cell.css("background-color", "green");
                    }
                },
```